# The cells in the tktable are blank instead of displaying content

Tags: python, tkinter

The example GUI in the imported TkTable module works fine. But when I try to use TkTable in my own work, every cell in the table is empty. My test code is below

```
from Tkinter import *
import TkTable

class App:

    def __init__(self, master): 
        """master is the top level window"""


        master.geometry(("%dx%d")%(250,60))
        master.title("Test")

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        var = TkTable.ArrayVar(frame)
        for y in range(6):
            for x in range(6):
                index = "%i,%i" % (y, x)
                var[index] = index

        label = Label(frame, text="test2")
        label.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

        quit = Button(frame, text="QUIT", command=root.destroy)
        quit.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'x')

        test = TkTable.Table(frame,
                 rows=6,
                 cols=6,
                 state='disabled',
                 width=6,
                 height=6,
                 titlerows=1,
                 titlecols=0,
                 roworigin=0,
                 colorigin=0,
                 selectmode='browse',
                 selecttype='row',
                 rowstretch='unset',
                 colstretch='last',
                 flashmode='on',
                 variable=var,
                 usecommand=0)
        test.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        test.tag_configure('sel', background = 'yellow')
        test.tag_configure('active', background = 'blue')
        test.tag_configure('title', anchor='w', bg='red', relief='sunken')


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The window displayed has a table with all empty cells.

I'm using Python 2.6, Mac OS 10.6, and Eclipse PyDev though I don't think any of that matters. What I think does matter, but I can't pinpoint why, is that the example code ( http://tkinter.unpy.net/wiki/TkTableWrapper ) provided in the TkTable module I downloaded from SourceForge runs the table in a slightly different way. It has:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_test()
```

where sample_test() contains

```
root = Tk()
```

and

```
root.mainloop()
```

Why does that example method work but mine does not? Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read up on **local variables** versus **global variables** versus **instance variables**!

Replace all occurrences of `var` with `self.var`.

Answer (score 0):

change your script:

```
for y in range(6):
    for x in range(6):
        index = "%i,%i" % (y, x)
        var[index] = index
```

to:

```
for y in range(6):
    for x in range(6):
        index = "%i,%i" % (y, x)
        var.set(index,index)
```

Comment: Please don't only code, but also a short description why.